# How to install Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I am installing the Laravel framework in directory `/var/html/www`, using command

```
php composer.phar global require "laravel/installer"
```

It changes installation directory automatically, shown message is:

> Changed current directory to /home/.composer

What is the reason? Do I need to add any other command?

Comment: What operating system you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because you installed the Laravel installer with `global`, which makes it globally available for all projects and installs it to `/home/.composer`.

This should be all right because it is only Laravel's **installer** and not a Laravel **project** which should be created in a later step (see below) and this should be installed in your `/var/html/www` then.

Run the following command in your `/var/html/www` to create a new project (doesn't need Laravel installer):

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel YourProjectName 5.2
```

or use the Laravel installer

```
laravel new YourProjectName
```

For more info how to install Laravel see the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2).

Comment: thank you peh, now i have installed laravel 5.2 successfully.

Comment: Hi, You can install Laravel in multiple ways. As you have tried installing the 'laravel/installer', that means you are willing to use the 'laravel' as command like *laravel new YOUR_PROJECT_NAME'*, which you should do by CDing into /var/www/html.

Whereas Installing the laravel App via Composer is as informed by @Peh which also is the better way, but for that you need not run 'composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"'.

Comment: @Peh, I appreciate your such a quick response and edit to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Take this link as a reference... http://www.tisuchi.com/laravel-5-series-episode-1-install-laravel-5/

Comment: In my case it works only if `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel YourProjectName "5.2.*"`

Answer (score 1):

Let use

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name "5.2.*"
```

Answer (score -2):

1) change the permission of your directory to allow CRUD.
Open Terminal and paste this command

```
sudo chmod -R o+rw /var/html/www
```

2) update the package manager cache by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3) cd to your directory to check if composer json does exist

```
cd /var/html/www
```

and type

```
composer
```

4) To install composer in your directory run

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

5) To test if it's installed run

```
composer
```

6) Now install laravel 5.2 in your directory (/var/html/www)

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel ProjectName 5.2 --prefer-dist
```

Comment: why the heck does he need to `apt-get update`? And he already installed composer, he doesn't need these steps!

Comment: To update the package manager and to make sure the server has all dependencies installed. for developers' sake..

Comment: This is definitely not needed to install Laravel and even not to install Composer (and he already has Composer installed). Sorry but I have to say this is not an appropriate answer to the question he asked!